# Web Scraping from Wikipedia into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to get the row data from a wikipedia page [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-followed_Instagram_accounts). So far I have been able to extract the column data but extracting the row data is a not working.
Here is what I have so far that worked:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-followed_Instagram_accounts'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html') 


celeb_titles = soup.find('tr')
celeb_table_titles = [title.text.strip() for title in celeb_titles] #list comp. to get titles in a list. needed help for this
while ('' in celeb_table_titles): #remove empty spaces
    celeb_table_titles.remove('')

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = celeb_table_titles)
column_data = soup.find_all('th')
```

This is where I am having issues:

```
for row in column_data:
    row_data = (row.find_all('td'))
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data] 
    print(individual_row_data)
```

I supposed to have my row data put in a list for me. The list should contain the same values as the Wikipedia one.

Comment: `'' in celeb_table_titles` why do you look for empty string ?

Comment: Because it initial prints our list with empty strings

Answer (score 2):

As @HedgeHog says, just use `pandas.read_html`. But here is a version that corrects the `Brand account` column:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-followed_Instagram_accounts"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

# correct Brand Account column for pd.read_html:
for t in soup.select('[title="Yes"]'):
    t.replace_with("Yes")

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(soup)))[0].fillna("")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   Rank             Username                  Owner        Brand account Followers (millions)              Profession/Activity                             Country
0                     1           @instagram              Instagram                  Yes                  661            Social media platform                       United States
1                     2           @cristiano      Cristiano Ronaldo                                       609                       Footballer                            Portugal
2                     3            @leomessi           Lionel Messi                                       490                       Footballer                           Argentina
3                     4         @selenagomez           Selena Gomez                                       430             Musician and actress                       United States
4                     5         @kyliejenner           Kylie Jenner                                       399                Media personality                       United States
5                     6             @therock         Dwayne Johnson                                       391  Actor and professional wrestler                       United States
6                     7        @arianagrande          Ariana Grande                                       380             Musician and actress                       United States
7                     8       @kimkardashian         Kim Kardashian                                       364                Media personality                       United States
8                     9             @beyonce                Beyoncé                                       318                         Musician                       United States
9                    10     @khloekardashian       Khloé Kardashian                                       311                Media personality                       United States
10                   11                @nike                   Nike                  Yes                  305         Sportswear multinational                       United States
11                   12       @kendalljenner         Kendall Jenner                                       294                Media personality                       United States
12                   13        @justinbieber          Justin Bieber                                       293                         Musician                              Canada
13                   14              @natgeo    National Geographic                  Yes                  283                         Magazine                       United States
14                   15         @taylorswift           Taylor Swift                                       274                         Musician                       United States
15                   16         @virat.kohli            Virat Kohli                                       261                        Cricketer                               India
16                   17                 @jlo         Jennifer Lopez                                       252             Musician and actress                       United States
17                   18          @nickiminaj            Nicki Minaj                                       227                         Musician  Trinidad and Tobago  United States
18                   19     @kourtneykardash    Kourtney Kardashian                                       224                Media personality                       United States
19                   20          @mileycyrus            Miley Cyrus                                       215             Musician and actress                       United States
20                   21            @neymarjr                 Neymar                                       215                       Footballer                              Brazil
21                   22           @katyperry             Katy Perry                                       206                         Musician                       United States
22                   23             @zendaya                Zendaya                                       185               Actress and singer                       United States
23                   24      @kevinhart4real             Kevin Hart                                       179               Comedian and actor                       United States
24                   25           @iamcardib                Cardi B                                       168             Musician and actress                       United States
25                   26           @kingjames           LeBron James                                       158                Basketball player                       United States
26                   27            @ddlovato            Demi Lovato                                       157             Musician and actress                       United States
27                   28          @badgalriri                Rihanna                                       152                         Musician                            Barbados
28                   29          @realmadrid         Real Madrid CF                  Yes                  148                    Football club                               Spain
29                   30  @chrisbrownofficial            Chris Brown                                       144                         Musician                       United States
30                   31       @champagnepapi                  Drake                                       143                         Musician                              Canada
31                   32      @ellendegeneres        Ellen DeGeneres                                       139     Comedian and television host                       United States
32                   33         @fcbarcelona           FC Barcelona                  Yes                  124                    Football club                               Spain
33                   34        @billieeilish          Billie Eilish                                       110                         Musician                       United States
34                   35     @championsleague  UEFA Champions League                  Yes                  110        Club football competition                              Europe
35                   36           @gal_gadot              Gal Gadot                                       109                          Actress                              Israel
36                   37            @k.mbappe          Kylian Mbappé                                       109                       Footballer                              France
37                   38           @vindiesel             Vin Diesel                                       101                            Actor                       United States
38                   39        @lalalalisa_m                   Lisa                                      98.3                         Musician                            Thailand
39                   40                @nasa                   NASA                  Yes                 96.6                     Space agency                       United States
40                   41      @priyankachopra        Priyanka Chopra                                      89.7                          Actress                               India
41                   42             @shakira                Shakira                                      89.5                         Musician                            Colombia
42                   43             @dualipa               Dua Lipa                                      88.7                         Musician             United Kingdom  Albania
43                   44        @davidbeckham          David Beckham                                      84.6                Former footballer                      United Kingdom
44                   45      @shraddhakapoor        Shraddha Kapoor                                      83.9                          Actress                               India
45                   46                 @nba                    NBA                  Yes                 83.6   Professional basketball league               United States  Canada
46                   47           @snoopdogg             Snoop Dogg                                      82.3                         Musician                       United States
47                   48      @jennierubyjane                 Jennie                                      81.7                         Musician                         South Korea
48                   49             @khaby00             Khaby Lame                                      80.9                Media personality                      Italy  Senegal
49                   50        @narendramodi          Narendra Modi                                      80.5          Prime Minister of India                               India
50  As of November 2023  As of November 2023    As of November 2023  As of November 2023  As of November 2023              As of November 2023                 As of November 2023
```

Answer (score 1):

While using `pandas` may use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) for scraping tables:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-followed_Instagram_accounts')[0][:-1].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

|  | Rank | Username | Owner | Followers (millions) | Profession/Activity | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | @instagram | Instagram | 661 | Social media platform | United States |
| 1 | 2 | @cristiano | Cristiano Ronaldo | 609 | Footballer | Portugal |
| 2 | 3 | @leomessi | Lionel Messi | 490 | Footballer | Argentina |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 46 | 47 | @snoopdogg | Snoop Dogg | 82.3 | Musician | United States |
| 47 | 48 | @jennierubyjane | Jennie | 81.7 | Musician | South Korea |
| 48 | 49 | @khaby00 | Khaby Lame | 80.9 | Media personality | Italy Senegal |
| 49 | 50 | @narendramodi | Narendra Modi | 80.5 | Prime Minister of India | India |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.read_html`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(page.text)[0]
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
  Rank      Username              Owner Brand account Followers (millions)  \
0    1    @instagram          Instagram           NaN                  661   
1    2    @cristiano  Cristiano Ronaldo           NaN                  609   
2    3     @leomessi       Lionel Messi           NaN                  490   
3    4  @selenagomez       Selena Gomez           NaN                  430   
4    5  @kyliejenner       Kylie Jenner           NaN                  399   

     Profession/Activity        Country  
0  Social media platform  United States  
1             Footballer       Portugal  
2             Footballer      Argentina  
3   Musician and actress  United States  
4      Media personality  United States
```